# Harmonic maps in the cotangent bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

$M$ is a Riemannian manifold with metric $g$ and we have a map $F: M \to T^{\*}M$ with $F(p)=(p,f(p))$ with a 1-form $f$. On $T^{*}M$ we use the Sasaki-metric.

How can I prove or it is wrong?:

$F$ is harmonic iff $f$ is harmonic.

Thank you and best regards.

Comment: What is the difference between f and F?

Comment: Why don't you sit down and actually compute, relative to a local coordinate system, what the tension-field/energy-density is, and what the local coordinate expressions for harmonicity is for the map $F$ and for the one-form $f$?

Comment: When I compute this, I have to inverse the following metric 

$g^{\prime}_{ij}=g_{ij}+\left( \frac{\partial f^{k}}{\partial x^{i}}\delta_{kn}-f^{t}\delta_{tk}\Gamma_{in}^{k} \right)g^{nM} \left( \frac{\partial f^{a}}{\partial x^{j}}\delta_{aM}-f^{a}\delta_{ab}\Gamma_{jM}^{b} \right).$

Can you help me to get the inverse metric?

Comment: Oh, now I understood the question.

Comment: What's the Sasaki metric on the cotangent bundle? I'm not familiar with this. (This looks like a straightforward formal computation, and it is unlikely that you need to find an explicit formula for the inverse of $g'_{ij}$ to do the calculation. Just call it $g'^{ij}$ and plunge ahead.)

Comment: I imagine the Sasaki metric on the cotangent bundle is like http://www.springerlink.com/content/m70m5w30522x7643/ , which construction is basically the same as the case for the tangent bundle. It is probably equivalent to the one given on the first page of http://www.springerlink.com/content/pmu535q8x3jqv711/ for tangent bundles under obvious changes from forms to vector fields. 

Comment: But I have to compute the tension field and for this I need the inverse metric. It is not correct?

Comment: Still, could you include the def of Sasaki metric?

Comment: You need to use the inverse metric but you don't need an explicit formula for it. The implicit definition $gg^{-1} = 1$ is all you need. 

Answer (score 2):

It is perhaps easier to look at the the harmonicity as Euler Lagrange equations for some action functional. The energy density of the map $F$ can be computed to be $$e_F = N + |\nabla f|^2$$
directly using the definition of the Sasaki metric. $N$ is the dimension of the manifold. So the Euler-Lagrange equation gives that the equation satisfied by $f$ for $F$ to be a harmonic map is 
$$ \triangle_g f = 0$$ 
On the other hand, for $f$ to be a harmonic one-form, you need
$$ (d\delta + \delta d) f = 0 $$
The Weitzenbock formula tells us that the two equations differ by a term coming from the Riemann curvature of $(M,g)$. So no, in general the two expressions are not equal.